# Angular 1.5 custom validation in relation to external values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does someone know if a custom validation with custom directive can be made in relation to some other values besides the bounded one?

E.g.

I have an array of objects of type Type1 which has fields Field1, Field2, Field3.

With ng-repeat I render the array and bind to some inputs the Field1.

What I would need to achieve, if possible with Angular 1.5, is the validation of Field1 in relation with Field2 and Field3.

**UPDATE**:

This is how my custom validation directive looks:

```
app.directive('customValidationDirective', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {

        debugger;
        //here I can see/access data attributes e.g. attr.controlinfos

        function validationHandler(value) {

            debugger;
            //here I have access only to new value in the input element

            //this is what I need here
            //I tried to access DOM element here but how can I pass it's name? because inputs are rendered dinamically with ng-repeat

            if ('value meets condition in relation to some other values from attr.controlinfos')
            {
                mCtrl.$setValidity('invalid', true);
            } else {
                mCtrl.$setValidity('invalid', false);
            }

            return value;
        }

        mCtrl.$validators.push(validationHandler);
    }
};
```

Please see comments in above code.

And this is how I use it HTML:

```
  <form name="modelForm">
<table class="table span8">
    <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="control in value | filter: {'TagControlType': 'Input'}">
            <td>
                <span data-ng-bind="::control.TagName | prettyName" title="{{::control.TagDescription}}"></span>
                <span style="color: red" data-ng-if="::control.TagMandatory">*</span>
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" data-ng-if="control.InputType == 'Numeric'"
                       data-ng-model="control.TagValue" title="{{::control.TagDescription}}"
                       data-ng-class="{required: isInvalid(control)}"
                       data-ng-required custom-validation-directive
                       id="{{::control.TagName}}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just pass Field2 and Field3 as attributes on your custom directive?

Answer (score 0):

You want Field 1 to be dependent on Field 2 and Field 3, correct?

Without knowing too much about your variables etc, I have created a simple solution.

Template:

```
<input class="field-one" ng-model='ctrl.fieldOne'></input>
<input class="field-two" 
       ng-change='ctrl.filterFieldOne()' 
       ng-model='ctrl.fieldTwo'></input>
<input class="field-three" 
       ng-change='ctrl.filterFieldOne()' 
       ng-model='ctrl.fieldThree'></input>
```

Ctrl:

```
class ctrl {
  /** @export {!Array<string>} **/
  this.fieldOne = [];

  /** @export {!Array<string>}  **/
  this.fieldTwo = [];

  /** @export {!Array<string>} **/
  this.fieldThree = [];

  /**
  * Takes in the controller variables (fieldTwo, fieldThree) and filters the fieldOne variable, and then resets fieldOne variable.
  */
  filterFieldOne() {
     const combinationFieldTwoFieldThree =  [...this.fieldTwo, ...this.fieldThree];
     const filterObj = this.fieldOne.filter(f => !combinationFieldTwoFieldThree.includes(f));
     this.fieldOne = Object.assign({}, filterObj);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, it's custom validation what I need not filtering